# Access S3 images uploaded through 'multer' from Angular frontend

Tags: node.js, angular, amazon-s3, multer, multer-s3

I'm creating a node js based server that has the ability to upload images to S3 using Multer. I am able to successfully upload the images.

Now when I am trying to retrieve the images in my html page, with the image URL like "https://s3.abcdefg.amazonaws.com/com.app.mybucket/5d6e127dc4022e291f68a045-0a0adfba80cd77b7e5399c0a1cba34a5270a.jpg" its throwing error:

```
<Error>
<Code>AccessDenied</Code>
<Message>Access Denied</Message>
<RequestId>DF7351BBCF515710</RequestId>
<HostId>
DWeAXRoc4xc9iHW9o2K29JO92Y636ghH2Fw9Kq96jG51naOXNpXmYkOHeUBMl/sLZlyqrLoT3GU=
</HostId>
</Error>
```

How can I resolve the problem without using Amazon SDK in my frontend (Angular)

Comment: What are your S3 bucket permissions?

Comment: @Kishan Public permissions for both read & write. I am trying to make it work. Later I've to make it public read and write only by load balancer